# Can I use multiple ARIA roles on a parent element

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Can I have multiple roles on a parent element for example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" role="rowheader">
        <p>Access to our award-wi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3" role="row gridcell" >  <<<
        <img src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/books/images/icon_tick_table.png" role="gridcell"
             alt="" title="s" class="table-image"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <img src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/form/hello.jpg" role="gridcell"
             alt=": Yes" title="s" class="table-image"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

[WAI-ARIA’s `role` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/host_languages#host_general_role) can have a list of values, but only the first valid and supported WAI-ARIA role will be used:

> The first name literal of a non-abstract WAI-ARIA role in the list of tokens in the role attribute defines the role according to which the user agent **MUST** process the element.

From the *User Agent Implementation Guide* about [Role mapping](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-implementation-20140320/#mapping_role):

> […] WAI-ARIA allows multiple roles to be specified as an ordered set of space-separated valid role tokens. The additional roles are fallback roles similar to the concept of specifying multiple fonts in case the first choice font type is not supported.